# Performing XOR byte comparisons with chars

Tags: c, byte, xor

I'm trying to perform an XOR byte operation on every 3rd byte in an unsigned char array in my program.  I'm having a type conversion error occur when I attempt to compile the program.

my declarations

```
unsigned char *s;
FILE *fp;
char ch;
int count = 0;
unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char));
int i = 0;

s = "s";
```

and this is where the error is occurring...

```
for (i = 3; i < count;)
{
    temp = (load[i-1] ^ s);
    temp2 = (load[i] ^ s);
            i = i + 3;
}
```

once I can get the XOR operation to work, I'll be setting load[i-1] = temp, right now I'm just trying to get the operation to compile and hopefully work.

Thanks in advance for any help / insight.

EDIT*  Updated to give temp data type and show how unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char)) is being used to take from data from a file.

```
char temp, temp2;


while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    load[i++] = ch;
}
```

and here is the error it is producing...

main.c:14:4: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char [2]' converts between pointers to
      integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]

```
    s = "s";
      ^ ~~~
```

main.c:86:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'unsigned char *')

```
            temp = (load[i-1] ^ s);
                    ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
```

main.c:87:20: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'unsigned char *')

```
            temp2 = (load[i] ^ s);
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal repro of the problem you're seeing? At the moment, this code doesn't make any sense, for example because temp and temp2 aren't defined.

Comment: Change to this: unsigned char *load = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));

Comment: char temp, temp2 is how temp is declared.

Comment: unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char)); works with while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { load[i++] = ch; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating memory to hold only one `unsigned char` in

```
unsigned char *load = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Then you are trying access the third character using `load[i-1]`.

**Update**

The compiler error is very clear about the nature of the error

```
main.c:86:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'unsigned char *')

        temp = (load[i-1] ^ s);
```

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
        temp = (load[i-1] ^ s[0]);
```

About the other compiler message, you can take care of that by initializing `s` when it is defined.

```
unsigned char *s = "S";
```

instead of assigning to it later.

Comment: You stated problem (one of them) well.  But not sure OP question is clearly answered.

Comment: The OP's question is not clearly answered since the types of `temp` and `temp2` are not known.

Comment: edited the post to give more clarity, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this took care of most of the compile problems.

Comment: An alternative, arguably simpler, solution to using `s[0]` is to define: `unsigned char s = 's';`.

Comment: thank you Jonathan, that solution removed a warning.  Interestingly I get two slightly different read outs with both versions.